# Call stack only shows third party libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, opencv

On crash of my program Visual Studio gives me the below call stack which has not one reference to any code Iv written or line number in my source, does this suggest there is a bug in the OpenCV library ?

I would of thought it would be still be possible to find the source  operation /function in my program which triggered the crash as is usually the case..

```
    opencv_imgproc243d.dll!cv::RGB2RGB<unsigned char>::operator()(const unsigned char * src=0x00000000, unsigned char * dst=0x0f010050, int n=1920)  Line 208 + 0x6 bytes   C++
>   opencv_imgproc243d.dll!cv::CvtColorLoop_Invoker<cv::RGB2RGB<unsigned char> >::operator()(const cv::Range & range={...})  Line 176 + 0x1d bytes  C++
    opencv_core243d.dll!`anonymous namespace'::ParallelLoopBodyWrapper::operator()(const cv::Range & sr={...})  Line 134 + 0x17 bytes   C++
    opencv_core243d.dll!`anonymous namespace'::ProxyLoopBody::operator()(int i=0)  Line 177 C++
    opencv_core243d.dll!Concurrency::_Parallel_chunk_helper_invoke<int,unsigned int,`anonymous namespace'::ProxyLoopBody,0>::_Invoke(const int & _First=0, unsigned int & _Index=0, const `anonymous-namespace'::ProxyLoopBody & _Func={...})  Line 1445    C++
    opencv_core243d.dll!Concurrency::_Parallel_chunk_helper<int,unsigned int,`anonymous namespace'::ProxyLoopBody,0>::operator()()  Line 1833 + 0x16 bytes  C++
    opencv_core243d.dll!Concurrency::task_handle<Concurrency::_Parallel_chunk_helper<int,unsigned int,`anonymous namespace'::ProxyLoopBody,0> >::operator()()  Line 116 C++
    opencv_core243d.dll!Concurrency::details::_UnrealizedChore::_InvokeBridge<Concurrency::task_handle<Concurrency::_Parallel_chunk_helper<int,unsigned int,`anonymous namespace'::ProxyLoopBody,0> > >(Concurrency::task_handle<Concurrency::_Parallel_chunk_helper<int,unsigned int,`anonymous namespace'::ProxyLoopBody,0> > * _PChore=0x036fb148 {_M_first=0 _M_step=1 _M_function={...} ...})  Line 3495   C++
    msvcr100d.dll!Concurrency::details::_UnrealizedChore::_StructuredChoreWrapper(Concurrency::details::_UnrealizedChore * pChore=0x036fb148 {_M_first=0 _M_step=1 _M_function={...} ...})  Line 99 + 0xc bytes C++
    msvcr100d.dll!Concurrency::details::_UnrealizedChore::_Invoke()  Line 3454 + 0xc bytes  C++
    msvcr100d.dll!Concurrency::details::WorkItem::Invoke()  Line 75 C++
    msvcr100d.dll!Concurrency::details::InternalContextBase::ExecuteChoreInline(Concurrency::details::WorkItem * pWork=0x0fb8f7dc)  Line 1385   C++
    msvcr100d.dll!Concurrency::details::InternalContextBase::Dispatch(Concurrency::DispatchState * pDispatchState=0x0fb8f7fc)  Line 1478    C++
    msvcr100d.dll!Concurrency::details::FreeThreadProxy::Dispatch()  Line 157   C++
    msvcr100d.dll!Concurrency::details::ThreadProxy::ThreadProxyMain(void * lpParameter=0x029c2160)  Line 162   C++
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x12 bytes    
    ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

Looks like an assertion failed as a result of a function recieving a corrrupted Mat as this was output to the console at the time of the crash.
[image]

Comment: uhm "the" call stack. well as you can see at the bottom, that's the call stack of some worker thread. each thread necessarily has its own stack

Comment: If you get such an "Assertion failed" messages, this usually means that you passed wrong input parameters to an OpenCV function. Would you post the code from line 434?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks that makes sense.. I'm guessing that this must be a thread created by OpenCV because it doesn't look like one that I have explicitly created.

Comment: @Niko I know that.. line 434 is opencv source.. its not much point in looking at that until I find what line in my code triggered it.. I have a several thousand lines code using opencv so...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : Im new to Visual Studio, and don't have a great amount experience with C++ thats my excuse.. :) .. its still no excuse but anyway... after digging around a little it looks like what I should do the next time I get this or a similar crash is to use the threads window view the call stacks for the other threads in the application, or do you have a better suggestion ?

Comment: @voting: i doubt main call stack will help you because it has undoubtedly progressed to something else. that's what threads are about. but thinking about where you could possibly be spinning off a worker thread, the only possibility leaping to mind is when you set the image of an opencv highgui window. but i don't really know, very limited experience with opencv. so i asked the folks in the c++ lounge to help you. maybe someone will. or, just go there and plead your case, mention me to avoid being branded spammer (i'll be it instead then :-) ).

Comment: @volting: Yeah, the crash means that _at some previous point_, you either (A) gave OpenCV invalid data, or (B) invalidated data that OpenCV was using.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks -That's the problem I guess.. I know where and all *my* worker threads are created which is at app startup.. and this crash happened much later.. and I'm not any highgui window so its not that, Im using Qt.. anyway your comments have helped, atleast Ill have a know what Im lookin at the next time I see a stacktrace like this.

Comment: @MooingDuck -Thats what I originally thought ..the problem is that there is no reference that I can see to any code that Iv written to help me find where this is happening.. surely there has to be a way to debug these sort crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll hazard a guess that when the method cvtColor() is called in your code that opencv runs this in its own thread.

You can see the opencv source [here](http://fossies.org/dox/OpenCV-2.4.3/imgproc_2src_2color_8cpp_source.html) which shows that this method is called in the Color.cpp file.

The RGB2RGB format is similar to that used in converting from one color space to another, i would guess that this is perhaps creating a copy.

As such i might look in your code for the following commands as the cause.

```
cvtColor(src, dst, CV_RGB2RGB);
or 
Mat A = Mat(...);
Mat B = A.clone();

I don't think this will cause it as this just copies header information.
Mat B(A);

or

A.copyTo(B);
```

You can rule out Mat's where you've converted them to BGR or GRAY. In fact given, as i understand it, that opencv works in the BGR color space, you've most likely somewhere converted a Mat to RGB already, which might make a good starting point to search from.

**Edit**

The assertion also suggests that your trying to clone() an empty Mat to another.

```
Asset(   y==0   )
```

If this only happens occasionally then i'd look for if() statements, or conditional situations where cloning or conversion is occurring.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed it might be something like that.. But I was interestd in the first place as how to debug stack traces like the one.. I guess there isn't any quick and easy way.. I'm surprised that OpenCV is running this it's own thread as I built it with out support for TBB. I guess the only thing to for now is to try to find any potential hazardous operations and wait to see if it crashes again in the same way

Comment: To debug stack traces like this you have to form a supposition, based on the information found in the classes listed and see where you end up. For example, based on my previous encounters of cvtColor i new it was related to conversion. The RGB2RGB isn't strictly a conversion so i guessed it might be a copy. So yeah, just luck i guess.

Comment: The stack trace has BaseThreadInitThunk and ThreadProxy. I know not what either may be, but perhaps the "Proxy" suggests this is a single thread pretending to be multi threaded. Who knows. Just because "Thread" is in a word perhaps doesn't mean its threaded.

Comment: Thanks @Emile you've given me lots of food for thought.. and I think I'm better equipped to debug these sort of issues now because of it...